# creating an array of objects using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have found it practical to use Java Streams to create large arrays of objects as in:

```
double[] doubleArray = {array of double};
DoubleWrapper[] wrapperArray = new DoubleWrapper[doubleArray.length;
IntStream
     .range(0, doubleArray.length)
     .forEach(index -> wrapperArray.setElement(index, myArray[index]));
```

It works. But I read that it is bad practice to rely on "side effects" but should get my desired result as the output of the stream.

I think I am getting closer to this when extracting the array from the object:

```
DoubleWrapper[] wrapperArray = {array of DoubleWrapper}
double[] mArray = IntStream
                    .range(0, divisor.size())
                    .mapToDouble(index ->  wrapperArray.getElement(index))
                    .toArray();
```

Is there a better way of doing this with streams? If not, should I go back to using "for loops"?

Comment: Your variables are bit confusing where does `myArray` comes from? can you please tide up a bit and add a example of input and output?

Comment: "myArray" is being defined in the first part of the line: "double[] myArray". Then it is assigne the output of the stream "= IntStream.range  ....  .toArray()".      I didn't want to use my code to avoid complexity. I'll work out a simple working example and upload it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Instead of looping through indices, and then getting the element of the array by index, you should loop through the array elements directly, by turning the array into a stream:

```
double[] mArray = Stream.of(wrapperArray)
   .mapToDouble(DoubleWrapper::getValue)
   .toArray();
```

or

```
DoubleWrapper[] wrapperArray = DoubleStream.of(doubleArray)
    .mapToObj(DoubleWrapper::new)
    .toArray(length -> new DoubleWrapper[length])
```

But the biggest mistake is probably to have your own DoubleWrapper class instead of using java.lang.Double, and to use arrays of objects instead of higer-level collections (like Lists, Sets, etc.)

Comment: Merci beaucoup JB. -- Works like a charm. I'm replacing all my IntStream by streaming the arrays. Much prettier. I considered extending Double or Number for my class but decided against. I chose arrays instead of collections in the perhaps mistaken impression that it would give me faster performance.